# PHP secure session and cookies

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I don't understand why we have to secure the cookies and session, I have a cookie that store userid, username encrypted password.

I have a function that checks the cookies at any moment if is the information matches with DataBase information,  if not, redirect to login page.
however I don't understand the risk with that can view this information and what he can do with this information.

Can anyone explain to me what is risk ?

Comment: First off, if your password is encrypted and not hashed, you are less secure than the ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to quantify in exact terms. First, remember that cookies are transferred between the client and the server **in every single request**. That's potentially many opportunities for someone to intercept them. Just assume that cookies *will* be intercepted at some point by somebody.

Storing the username, userid and (encrypted) password in the cookie:

- leaks information which may or may not be useful or usable for nefarious purposes; i.e. for a successful login you need a username and a password, and you are waving both high up in the air shouting **CAPTURE ME**, the username even in plaintext
- relies solely on the secrecy of your encryption algorithm for the password; if it becomes known, you have quite a security problem

  - since the encrypted password is known, an offline brute force attack can be mounted against it to reveal the encryption algorithm and plaintext password; this attack may or may not be purely theoretical, the fact that it exists at all should bother you
  - if it is possible at all to *decrypt* the password, you have already lost; the password is a *secret* only the user alone should know, not even you want to know at any point what the password is; if you *do* know the password, you have a giant responsibility to safeguard it, certainly you do not want to send it back and forth over HTTP the whole time; → see *password hashing*
- gives you no control over anything, all login information rests with the client (i.e. *what do you do if you know any of the above was compromised?*)
- does not let you change passwords without invalidating all active logins

On the other hand, using only a meaningless session id:

- reveals no useful information in the cookies
- no opportunity to crack or brute force anything of value
- server holds the ultimate power since sessions can be revoked at any time
- it's simpler (simpler is always good in security)
- using a full session with server-side state allows you to escalate privileges; e.g. require the user to have actively logged in with his password within the last *x* minutes from the current IP to allow him to change his password or email address → provides security even if the session cookie should be hijacked

In short: session ids present no *attack surface* at all, since they're inherently meaningless. Userids, names and passwords present a very juicy target. Just from those basic points sessions should seem a lot more appealing. Assuming a perfect implementation with otherwise perfect security, both should be rather secure. However, you do not know what insecurities you have, you *won't* have perfect security. Assuming this, *knowing* this, the simpler system with fewer caveats should always be preferable.

Comment: I see, so the risk if that someone can see the information that store in the cookies with some packet sniffer and take over the account.
if I store only ID for example, where i will store the password ? in session ?
it's a little problem because this session will be delete when the browser closed, and when user will return to the site how can I keep him logged in if 
i have only cookie that store only ID ?

Comment: You don't need to store the password anywhere! All you need to do is create a random (session) id and link that id to the user, that's all. Using sessions you'd simply start a session and save `$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid` to know who the user is, that's all you need. For something longer-lived than a session, you'd store similar information in a database. Note that sessions don't have to end "when the browser closes", you just need to configure the cookie and session timeouts appropriately.