# How to secure User ID inside cookie value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies

After logined user, I keep user ID inside cookie ($_COOKIE['user_id']) and after this mysql check if isset user_id inside cookie and if user_id is exists in DB:

```
SELECT * FROM users WEHERE user_id = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'
```

It works, but cookie value can be changed by every cliend, so client can set cookie user_id to 1 or 2,3,4 and it will be loggined, So they can hack page.

I want to hash or secure somehow my cookie user_id value. I hope you understand me.
Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need it in a cookie in this case instead of - for example - a session?

Comment: Session will be expire and I need automatically login, after users back on page...

Comment: Ok, then you'll basically need to either encrypt it, add a checksum (including the user id and a secret word) to the cookie or use a totally random value in the cookie that you can look up in the database.

Comment: SQL injection btw, better use prepared statements.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24251964/476

Answer (score 6):

Do not do that in a cookie. Save a hash in the cookie and store the corresponding user id in your database. You can't make the cookie secure.

To be more clear:

When the user logs in, store a unique hash for him in the database. This could be something like that: `sha512('9a7fd98asf'.time().$username)`. This is the value you save in the cookie, too. You know the user is logged in, if he has such a token in the database and if it matches the value from the cookie. This actually is how sessions are handled.

Comment: My users already stored in DB, what do you mean "save a hach in the cookie", how to hash my cookie? in which way?

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is if the user logs in from a second computer, updating the database with a new hash will invalidate his first login. Probably fixable, if you just consider when you actually need to regenerate the hash in the database.

Comment: Well if you don't have any security concerns there, you can simply save and allow __all__ hashes he ever generated with logins. Of course he would need to log in from every pc once, but that lies in the nature of cookies.

Comment: If there's no user info at client side but just a hash, when the user returns, how do you know which user the hash is for?

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are prone to numerous types of attacks including someone stealing a cookie from one user and presenting it later to impersonate that user. If you were to instead use sessions, you would either have to use session cookies or URL, both of which are problematic from a security point of view.

The best you could possibly do is encrypt the cookie so you can later decrypt it when you read the user_id. This will ensure that a user cannot randomly change their user_id. However, this does not protect against one user using the data from the cookie of another user.

To guard both against reply attacks (either by the same user, or by a different user), in addition to storing the user_id, you would also want to store the expiry time in the cookie. When you get back the cookie, you can decrypt and also get the time that you need. This does mean though that this type of replay attack is possible within that time during which cookie is valid.

For encryption/decryption, you can search and find how to correctly do it using the language you are employing. You will still have to test against corrupted cookies (in which case you can assume user is not authenticated).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a **meaningless token**. That's the most secure way, because the token is inherently meaningless and cannot be attacked in itself. Because the token also needs to be stored on the server with associated data, this also gives the server the ultimate control over logins; because the server can revoke active tokens at any time (you cannot revoke a cookie which stores just a self-contained user id).

A standard PHP session is such a meaningless token and works just fine for most cases. Sessions can even be configured to last extremely long, and you can even change the session storage backend to a database or any custom backend you want.
If, for whatever reason, you need something else, you still want the same idea:

- generate a completely random, meaningless value
- store it in a database, together with what user it belongs to
- send the token in a cookie to the client

Answer (score 1):

You could store an additional cookie, named 'user_hash':

`$_COOKIE['user_hash']=sha1($user_id . md5($user_pass . $salt1) . $salt2);`

Using some constant $salt values.

When using the user_id cookie, first check if user_hash matches the user login information stored in the database.

Since the sha1 is irreversible, the password cannot be derived from it.

Comment: So you say, that after every login I must keep `sha1($user_id . md5($user_pass . $salt1) . $salt2);` in DB and in cookie too?

Comment: Nope - it is derived from the $user_id and $user_pass stored in the database. Before you agree to use the $_COOKIE['user_id'], you load $user_id and $user_pass from the database, calculate the sha1, and check if $_COOKOE['user_hash'] is the same value.
Without the password, the token cannot be forged.